# Drawing heatmap in R; how can I restrict the amount of colors

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following numeric dataframe:

```
> cnv_n
       V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9
 [1,]  31  37  30  30  33  30  33  36  44
 [2,] 104 107  94 109 108 105  99 101 123
 [3,] 522 545 539 554 500 537 454 474 512
 [4,]  36  39  34  37  33  38  36  37  40
 [5,]  62  70  62  64  62  60  57  61  70
 [6,]  12  13   8   8  10   9  13  12  14
 [7,]  70  75  62  66  70  70  74  79  80
 [8,]  22  20  22  21  23  24  20  25  25
 [9,]  75  76  77  74  73  69  55  67  77
[10,]  40  46  39  43  38  39  38  38  41
[11,] 171 186 172 171 164 169 157 175 190
[12,]  47  56  51  55  49  45  55  46  53
[13,] 183 200 170 191 172 168 195 207 210
[14,] 175 165 161 187 174 199 152 166 180
[15,]   5   7   5   8   8   6   8   7   6
[16,]  71  80  69  78  70  76  66  78  83
[17,] 377 413 369 401 371 366 360 362 415
[18,] 191 187 187 199 184 181 195 192 221
[19,] 294 321 273 306 289 273 298 326 340
[20,]  30  31  32  29  29  28  22  24  30
[21,] 109 123 108 114 106 105 105 111 123
[22,] 446 461 441 474 433 440 408 443 489
[23,] 498 537 467 511 490 479 429 496 552
[24,] 354 401 333 371 367 370 348 385 423
[25,] 319 338 299 322 289 297 263 325 350
```

I need to draw a heatmap, and this can be done as simply as:

```
> heatmap(cnv_n)
```

I have a few questions about what this does. 
The dendogram rearranges the rows and columns together based on similarity to each other, correct?
If for some reason I do not want that done, I can do this:

```
heatmap(cnv_n, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```

So now the order is preserved.

I am interested to know what are the properties of this heatmap. It obviously determined automatically what ranges need to be assigned what color. How can I obtain a legend as to what color represents what number range in my dataframe?

What if I decide that the ranges R guessed are to lenient or too stringent and in fact all I want is a maximum of 10 colors?

I read the info for heatmap but I am not advanced enough to understand how to find out this info.

Thanks for your help.
Adrian

Comment: If you check out the `?heatmap` help page, you'll see it also recognizes the same parameters you would pass to `image`. If you just want 10 colors, pass a vector of 10 colors as the `col=` parameter, eg `col=heat.colors(10)`. You can also explicitly set the `breaks=` if you like so you know where the color values change.

Comment: Your question is probably too broad. Please have a look at [gplots::heatmap.2()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gplots/docs/heatmap.2) (especially at the `key` parameter) and at [ggplot2::geom_tile()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html) and return with a more specific question.